# Draw map based on selected city in selectbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, drop-down-menu, ng-options, city

i have a select box for city which has number of cities getting through ng-options. i need to show the map on the website based on city selected in the selectbox.
this is how i am getting city names

```
// Code goes here


$scope.data = [{
        cities: [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'Mysore'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Bangalore'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Delhi'
        }, {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Mumbai'
        }],
        maps: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Zoo',
                city_id: 1
            }, {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Palace',
                city_id: 1
            }, {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Beach',
                city_id: 4
            }]

    }];
});
```

Plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/r1S1e61H3RfH3uYGYTBP?p=preview 

 Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the coordinates to the `$scope`:

```
$scope.coordinates = {
  lat: 28.620089858889145,
  lng: 77.17483520507812
};
```

And:

```
<ng-map zoom="13" center="{{coordinates.lat}},{{coordinates.lng}}" ...
```

Use `ng-change` on the select:

```
ng-change="centerCity(citySelect.selectedOption)"
```

In the `centerCity` method you can use the geocoder to retrieve the coordinates by city name. Then you simply need to update the variables.

Simple example:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

$scope.centerCity = function(city) {

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': city.title
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.coordinates.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        $scope.coordinates.lng= results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      });

    } else {
      console.log('Error');
    }
  });
};
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/WETs0FL0DbPbDn2A77hq?p=preview

Comment: One more thing, The map select box in the plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/WETs0FL0DbPbDn2A77hq?p=preview will show options based on city now. so if i want the map to be shown based on the map (second) select box. it should search the map.title in the selected city in the first select box. how to do it

Comment: Try something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/NwxhxSipp60xBxS4DDCN?p=preview I don't know google maps well enough to know if those are valid search parameters however.

Comment: that plunker is almost working. but the problem is if i select mysore in city and select anyone in  map, it worked but after selecting one item in map. if i choose another one , it is not working